# Always get Infinity by caculating bouding box of object in A-Frame

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I use three.js to get bounding box of objects in A-Frame scene.

```
let boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(element.object3D);
```

But the 6 values in boundingBox are always Infinity or -Infinity as the default values of Three.Box3.

I tried it with a a-box in the basic example of A-Frame and one of my own gltf 2.0 model.

Project: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/get-bounding-box

Does someone know the reason? Or some methods to get bounding box in A-Frame?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calculating the bounding box before the actual model has loaded. Try it like this:

```
leftDoor.addEventListener( 'model-loaded', () => {

     getWorldBound( leftDoor );  

} );
```

Comment: Oh... did I have to use a fallback timeout because I used the `loaded` event instead of the better `model-loaded`? (cf own answer wrote at the same time as yours)

Answer (score 0):

The glTF mesh has to be actually loaded which takes time. Try instead something like

```
el.addEventListener('loaded', function() { doStuffWithModelSize(el); } );

function doStuffWithModelSize(el){
  var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( el.mesh );
  var width = bbox.max.x - bbox.min.x;
  var height = bbox.max.y - bbox.min.y;
  var depth = bbox.max.z - bbox.min.z;
  if (Number.isFinite( height ) ) { 
    // do stuff with those values
  } else { 
    window.setTimeout( () => { verticalAdjust(el) }, 2000)
    // sometimes it's actually still not enough to you can try until it is
  }
}
```